# integrating ARKit in Flutter App using swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, arkit

I’m trying to create app using flutter for both android and IOS and I need to integrate AR in my app for IOS using ARKit. How I can continue working using swift in IOS app?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, for now there is no such support in Flutter

> Today we don’t support for 3D via OpenGL ES or similar

[Official info](https://flutter.io/docs/resources/faq#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

There is a flutter library for ARCore and ARKit. You can use this library to implement ARCore for android and ARKit for Apple in the same App.

https://pub.dev/packages/ar_flutter_plugin