# ARCore and ARKit in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, arkit, arcore

Can someone explain how to use `ARCore` and `ARKit` in Flutter? 
Is there a canonical way?
Medium articles on this topic are pretty vague.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778473/integrating-arkit-in-flutter-app-using-swift